# GeoNetwork : names of the "inspire themes" don't appears anymore on the front page

Tags: geonetwork, inspire

On [my GeoNetwork server](https://dataset.osupytheas.fr/geonetwork/srv/fre/catalog.search#/home) ([v3.10.2](https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/tree/3.10.2)), I don't know why the names of the `"inspire themes"` don't appears anymore in the front page.

For instance I get `http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/theme/ac`
instead of `"atmospheric conditions"`.

- current one : [image: new inspire theme label]
- (kind of) desired one with a label title instead of an URL : [image]

I have emptied the cache, restarted GeoNetwork , but the problem still remains.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Same behavior seen here : https://www.inspire-geoportal.lt/geonetwork/srv/fre/catalog.search#/home. Maybe ask on the project Gitter : https://gitter.im/geonetwork/core-geonetwork or create a ticket on the project Github page : https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/issues.

Comment: When the page is loaded in english, this is fine : https://dataset.osupytheas.fr/geonetwork/srv/eng/catalog.search#/home and sort of related issue : https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/issues/2869